# Two Factor Authentication with MVC Security

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security

I have setup two factor authentication with mvc as per this article:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-sms-and-email-two-factor-authentication

This is done with cookies. Is it possible to persist the decision across browsers as cookies are browser specific. Is this how the likes of google handle two factor authentication

Comment: do you want implement two factor authentication with SMS or Email ?

Comment: Means implement either sms or email ?

Comment: am using both so the user can choose

Comment: its the cookie i am concerned with i.e. a user opens another browser and has to reconfirm again second time round

Comment: I implement only for sms. If u want some solution then I can share with you.

Comment: that would be great would you like my email

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65341/discussion-between-anurag-jain-and-user1853454).